# Points in a plane

Tags: vector-analysis

I have a question. 
Given are the points $a(1,3)$ and $b(-2,1)$. 
I have to compute $\|a\|$ and $\|a+b\|$, but I don't know how to do it.
Can someone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of a vector $v=(x,y,z)$, also called its norm is given by $$\mid \mid v \mid \mid =\sqrt {x^2+y^2+z^2} $$ In three dimensional space.

Here $a =(1,3,0) $, so $\mid \mid a \mid \mid =\sqrt {1^2+3^2+0} = \sqrt {10} $. Hope you can take it from here and proceed likewise for the second case.

Comment: Can I for the second case, just count a+b to get (-1,4) and do ||a+b|| = sqrt ((-1)^2+4^2)?

Comment: @user410573 Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude (length) of a vector $\vec t=(t_1,t_2,\cdots,t_n)$ is given by
$$||\vec t||=\sqrt{t_1^2+t_2^2+\ldots+t^2_n}$$

In this context, the vectors only have 2 component, so

$$||\vec A||=\sqrt{A_1^2+A_2^2}=\sqrt{1^2+3^2}=10$$

For the second part of question, we sum both vectors separately for every component. For instance

$$A=(a_1,a_2,a_3),B=(b_1,b_2,b_3)\implies A+B=(a_1+b_1,a_2+b_2,a_3+b_3)$$